# Doctrine2 Save Many To One Objects

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, many-to-one

The relation is: **MailTemplate** may be used by many **EMail** but **EMail** is associated only to one **MailTemplate**.

The problem occurs when trying to insert new records. The error is:

> Cannot access empty property

and appears in the `setEmail()` method

Definition of **MailTemplate**:

```
/**
* @Entity
* @Table(name="MailTemplate")
*/

class MailTemplate
{

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned":true})
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $mailtemplateID;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="EMail", inversedBy="MailTemplate")
     * @JoinColumn(name="emailID", referencedColumnName="emailID")
     **/
    protected $email = null;
    // ...
    public function setEmail(EMail $email)
    {
        $this->$email = $email;
    }
}
```

Definition of **EMail**:

```
/**
* @Entity
* @Table(name="EMail")
*/

class EMail
{

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned":true})
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $emailID;
    // ...
}
```

Then, I try to create my objects like so:

```
$mail_template = new MailTemplate();
$email = new EMail();

//... Adding values with the usual setter methods

$entity_manager->persist($email);
$entity_manager->flush($email);

$mail_template->setEmail($email);

$entity_manager->persist($mail_template);
$entity_manager->flush($mail_template);
```

I also tried with the `__construct()` method like so:

```
// Inside the MailTemplate class
public function __construct(EMail $email)
{
    $this->$email = $email;
}
```

But I always get the error mentioned above. What am I missing?

**Edit** (on noobie-php's comment). I've added this to the **EMail** entity:

```
/**
 * @Id
 * @Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned":true})
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="MailTemplate", mappedBy="EMail")
 * @JoinColumn(name="mailtemplateID", referencedColumnName="mailtemplateID")
 */
protected $emailID;
```

But still the same error occurs...

Comment: where is one to many relation?

Comment: @noobie-php In the docs (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) it doesn't say anything like that... Edited Title

Comment: well you must still implement it. And then run doctrine update command

Comment: @noobie-php. Ok thx I'll try

Comment: @noobie-php Nope, still the same. Do I have to define another property in the EMail entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the inversedBy="MailTemplate" you have to do in Email entity class :

```
/**
* @Entity
* @Table(name="EMail")
*/

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class EMail
{

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned":true})
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $emailID;

   /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="EMailTemplate", mappedBy="email")
     **/
    protected $mailTemplates = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->mailTemplates = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // getter and setters
```

**MailTemplate.php**

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="MailTemplate")
 */
 class MailTemplate
 {

        /**
         * @Id
         * @Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned":true})
         * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $mailtemplateID;

        /**
         * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="EMail")
         * @JoinColumn(name="emailID", referencedColumnName="emailID", nullable=true)
         **/
        protected $email = null;
        // ...
        public function setEmail(EMail $email)
        {
            $this->$email = $email;
        }
    }
```

Or simply remove inversedBy in $email property annotation on class MailTemplate

Comment: Nope... Start thinking that the eroor must be somewhere else... If I look at the DB definition it looks ok too... And if I insert data without relation it works also

Answer (score 0):

So, finally (as I tought) it was a stupid error.

I had to change the following things:

In the **EMail** entity:

- Changed `@OneToMany` into `@ManyToOne`.
- Added `inversedBy="EMail"`
- Added `cascade={"persist"}`

In the **MailTemplate** entity:

- Changed `@ManyToOne` into `@OneToMany`.
- Changed `inversedBy="MailTemplate"` into `mappedBy="MailTemplate"`

Then one may work with the constructor or a setter to fill data.